# angular directive was only called once

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using a directive to build a custom validator and it works fine. But, it was called only once! If my "roleItems" are updated, this directive was not called again! How can it be called every time when "roleItems" are updated?

Here are the markups. And "Not-empty" is my directive.

```
 <form name="projectEditor">    
    <ul name="roles" ng-model="project.roleItems" not-empty>
        <li ng-repeat="role in project.roleItems"><span>{{role.label}}</span> </li>
       <span ng-show="projectEditor.roles.$error.notEmpty">At least one role!</span>
      </ul>
    </form>
```

This is my directive. It should check if the ng-model "roleItems" are empty.

```
angular.module("myApp", []).
    directive('notEmpty', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

                ctrl.$validators.notEmpty = function (modelValue, viewValue) {


                    if(!modelValue.length){
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                };

            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: What do you intend ng-model to do on a ul? ng-model is used for bidirectional data binding on components like inputs, where the user can enter values, that are stored in a model variable. ul can't do that. This makes no sense. Just remove this directive and use <span ng-show="project.roleItems.length == 0">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main purpose of validator is validate ngModel value of user input or model change, so it should be uset to checkbox/textara/input and etc. You cant validate ng-model of everything. Angular is enough intelligent to knows that ng-model makes no sens so he is just ignoring it .

I you wanna change only error message you can check it via .length property. If you wanna make whole form invalid , i suggest you to make custom directive , put it on  , and then in validator of this directive check scope.number.length > 0

Basically just adjust your directive code to input element and hide it .... via css or type=hidden, but dont make ngModel="value" its not make sense because ng-model is expecting value which can be binded and overwriteen but project.roleItems is not bindable! so put ng-model="dummyModel" and actual items to another param ...

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="dummyIgnoredModel" number="project.roleItems" check-empty>


angular.module("myApp", []).
    directive('checkEmpty', function () {
        return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {

                ctrl.$validators.push(function (modelValue, viewValue) {


                    if(!scope.number.length){
                        return false;
                    }

                    return true;
                });
             //now we must "touch" ngModel
               scope.$watch(function()
               {
                  return scope.number
               }, function()
               {
                  ctrl.$setViewValue(scope.number.length);
               });
            }
        };
    });
```